# App Script - Send filtered table as HTML in Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

New to Apps scripts...

I'm trying to send a schedule, (a table in sheets), as HTML in an email.

I have managed to piece together a script that does what I want... mostly.

If I use the following range, the script works.
(This is the visible table filtered, where results happen to be in the first 26 rows)

```
var schedRange = sheet.getRange("A1:J26");
```

The problem is, the full table is "A1:J261", and when I use the full table range (so I can filter other criteria), I get:

```
Limit Exceeded: Email Body Size.
```

Can I specify only the filtered table, excluding all hidden content?

My end objective is to be able to:

1. Loop through available criteria of COL J, with some exceptions

   - (haven't started on this yet)
2. For each criteria, send table as HTML in email.

I've made a public version available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/144No7LKmWPwI2RTaqnnoH1ElLEbrAjbOuc7qKx5wu1M/edit?usp=sharing)

Any assistance is much appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around sending only visible only rows, I have a query setup from my original data table, that is dependant on a cell setup with data validation. (essentially a filter)

Instead of running a filter on the whole table, now my table is made up of only what I wanted filtered. (so no hidden rows)

The query looks like this:

```
=QUERY(DATA!A1:J,"select A, C, D, E, F, G, H, I where J = '"&E1&"'",+1)
```

Where E1 is the Company I want to email and the result of the query is the table I want to send them.

The following is the script I have been using for the last few months to send the booking email to each company (as a HTML table) within a Gmail email, from Google Sheets.

I can't locate/recall where the various snippets came from, so apologies for not referencing any authors that contributed to this function.

It works a treat for me, so hopefully, all of this can help you!

```
function sendEmail_draft() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length+1;
  var recipient = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue(); // "TO" email address
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  var subject = "DRAFT Booking - "+ sheet.getRange("E1").getValue()+ " ";
  subject +=  Utilities.formatDate(
                  sheet.getRange("D1").getValue(),
                  ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
                  "EEE, MMM d yyyy"),
                  sheet.getRange("D1").getValue()
  var schedRange = sheet.getRange("A3:H"+Alast); 

  // Put Name & Date into email first.
  // We only want the schedule within borders, so
  // these are handled separately.
  var body = '<div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif">'
  body += '<H1>'+ "COMPANY NAME "+ sheet.getRange("E1").getValue() +'</H1>';
  body += '<H2>'+ "WORKBOOK NAME:- "+ name +'</H2>';
  body += '<H2>'+ "Date of Booking - "
        + Utilities.formatDate(
            sheet.getRange("D1").getValue(),
            ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
            "EEEEE, MMMMM d, yyyy")
        + '</H2>';
  body += getHtmlTable(schedRange);
  body += '</div>';
  debugger;

  //recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();  // For debugging, send only to self
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "Requires HTML", {htmlBody:body})
}

/////////////

/**
 * Return a string containing an HTML table representation
 * of the given range, preserving style settings.
 */
function getHtmlTable(range){
  var ss = range.getSheet().getParent();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  startRow = range.getRow();
  startCol = range.getColumn();
  lastRow = range.getLastRow();
  lastCol = range.getLastColumn();

  // Read table contents
  var data = range.getValues();

  // Get css style attributes from range
  var fontColors = range.getFontColors();
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var fontFamilies = range.getFontFamilies();
  var fontSizes = range.getFontSizes();
  var fontLines = range.getFontLines();
  var fontWeights = range.getFontWeights();
  var horizontalAlignments = range.getHorizontalAlignments();
  var verticalAlignments = range.getVerticalAlignments();

  // Get column widths in pixels
  var colWidths = [];
  for (var col=startCol; col<=lastCol; col++) { 
    colWidths.push(sheet.getColumnWidth(col));
  }
  // Get Row heights in pixels
  var rowHeights = [];
  for (var row=startRow; row<=lastRow; row++) { 
    rowHeights.push(sheet.getRowHeight(row));
  }

  // Future consideration...
  var numberFormats = range.getNumberFormats();

  // Build HTML Table, with inline styling for each cell
  var tableFormat = 'style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:center" border = 1 cellpadding = 5';
  var html = ['<table '+tableFormat+'>'];
  // Column widths appear outside of table rows
  for (col=0;col<colWidths.length;col++) {
    html.push('<col width="'+colWidths[col]+'">')
  }
  // Populate rows
  for (row=0;row<data.length;row++) {
    html.push('<tr height="'+rowHeights[row]+'">');
    for (col=0;col<data[row].length;col++) {
      // Get formatted data
      var cellText = data[row][col];
      if (cellText instanceof Date) {
        cellText = Utilities.formatDate(
                     cellText,
                     ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
          'EEE, MMM dd YY'); ///          'EEE, MMM dd - h:mm a');
      }
      var style = 'style="'
                + 'color: ' + fontColors[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-family: ' + fontFamilies[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-size: ' + fontSizes[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-weight: ' + fontWeights[row][col]+'; '
                + 'background-color: ' + backgrounds[row][col]+'; '
                + 'text-align: ' + horizontalAlignments[row][col]+'; '
                + 'vertical-align: ' + verticalAlignments[row][col]+'; '
                +'"';
      html.push('<td ' + style + '>'
                +cellText
                +'</td>');
    }
    html.push('</tr>');
  }
  html.push('</table>');

  return html.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting the defined limit. This was mentioned in [Current limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas):

[image]

Comment: Yes, so my question - is there a way to only copy the visible cells shown in the auto-filter, instead of the entire array? 

I can get it to work for 30 rows, which is all I need when filtered, but don't know how to only copy the visible rows.